# Undefined function user_load()

Tags: 7, drush, debugging

My Drupal 7 installation works fine, except for drush, which does not.

> $ cd /srv/www/drupal_site
>
> $ drush pm-refresh
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function user_load() in
>   /usr/share/php/drush/includes/drupal.inc on line 138
>
> Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.
>
> Error: Call to undefined function user_load() in
>   /usr/share/php/drush/includes/drupal.inc, line 138
>
> Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) Drupal.

This is Drupal 7.24 and drush 5.10.0 from Debian. A couple of modules and themes have been installed from drupal.org but IMHO nothing fancy. Curent versions of drush6 or drush7 refer to a missing drupal_get_profile() function but otherwise don't help.

Any ideas what the cause of this problem is, and/or how to debug this?

EDIT: It works fine, except for these spurious error lines displayed on the web page (even though I do not use any sort of debug mode), as reported by a user:

> Notice: Undefined index: post-load integration files in `libraries_load_files()` (line 697 of /var/www/drupal7/modules/libraries/libraries.module).

This may or may not be related to my problem.

I tried using Drush 6.x/7.x, but it just returns a different error message.

> Call to undefined function `drupal_get_profile()` in /usr/share/php/drush/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 963

`drush cc` hits an error before it can do anything; the same happens with `drush rr`, which returns a different error, but equally intractable.

php-apc is not installed; I have Memcached, but killing it didn't change anything.
I did not change any module weights.

Comment: Are you having multisite environment?

Comment: While I do have multiple sites, they each have their own drupal subdirectory, symlinked to the Debian-installed Drupal.

Comment: @MatthiasUrlichs What's the result of: `drush status`. Do you have `Connected` and bootstrap says `Successful`?

Comment: I just ran into this issue yesterday in a Drupal 7 / Drush 5 environment.  Posting here in case anybody else runs into this.

My database import had failed because it had MySQL views without a proper creator on the instance where it was imported.

The odd thing was that 95% of the other structure was there, but it was missing a few tables.

Clear up your db import and then it should be able to fully bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

We got the same errors here.

After some time we recognized that our database-import (cloning production db to local dev machine) went wrong and the database wasn't populated properly. After fixing the db the errors went away...

So - my hint: check your database structure and data.

BTW: There is a [similar question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/99797/why-is-drush-cc-all-failing-with-undefined-function-user-load) - but with an memcached in the drupal setup

Comment: Hmm, "check your database structure and data" is rather open-ended. I did not manually manipulate any database settings or contents and did not deinstall any modules or whatever. The site itself works.

Comment: In our case the site itself didn't work either - also showing some "function not found" error in the browser.
And by checking I meant to look in the database for obvious problems, like tables without any data or tables missing (compared to the source/production database).