# Why is "drush cc all" failing with "undefined function user_load()"

Tags: drush, caching

After updating my Drupal test server to have a fresh copy of the database and code from the production system, "drush cc all" would fail with a message saying

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function user_load() in /usr/share/pear/drush/includes/drupal.inc on line 138

I'm running drush version 6.2.0 with a drupal 7.25 system. I'm using memcache as `cache_default_class`.

Comment: Can you clear caches via the Performance screen? Does the site work otherwise?

Comment: The site was completely dead, white screen and a fatal PHP error in the apache error log: "PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function system_run_automated_cron() in /srv/www/www.imsa.edu/drupal1/includes/common.inc on line 2706"

Comment: Sounds like you're missing some files. Are you sure you copied everything from production?

Comment: jmking, that's what I thought too, but I diffed the files between test and production and they matched exactly (except for settings.php, of course).

Answer (score 2):

The problem went away after I restarted memcached.

I discovered that by running drush with `-d` and seeing a PHP error about a `$theme` value not being a valid index. Tracing the code showed that access to `cache_bootstrap` was getting empty arrays for the module and theme data.

From now on I plan to restart memcached or flush its cache on my test server after rebuilding its database. (I've done this kind of rebuilding dozens of times before with no issues.)